# How to get the content from a Multiline text box using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to retrieve value from a multi line textbox using angular js, but am getting the div tags attached to the content. How can we retrieve only the content?

I have used following code:

```
var myAngApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp', []);

    myAngApp.controller('spCustomerController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $http({

            method: 'GET',

            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Questions')/items?$select=Description",

            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }

        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.customers = data.d.results;


        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {



        });


});
```

I am getting the content along with html div tags, but I need only the content

Comment: $scope.customers.innerText or  $scope.customers.innerHTML

Comment: I tried this inside angular expression{{$scope.customers.Description.innerText}}, but it is showing empty

Comment: Do you rich text content as plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting HTML content because you have enabled **Enhanced rich text**  option in your column.

[image]

## Solution No#1

Enable **Plain text** instead of **Enhanced rich text**

## Solution No#2

[Remove HTML tags using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822464/1294606)

```
    var myAngApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp', []);

myAngApp.controller('spCustomerController', function($scope, $http) {

    $http({

        method: 'GET',

        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Questions')/items?$select=Description",

        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }

    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      
      //remove all html tags
        data.d.results.forEach(function(customer) {
            customer["{InternalNameOfYourColumn}"] = customer["{InternalNameOfYourColumn}"].replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');;
        });
      
        $scope.customers = data.d.results;


    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {



    });


});
```

Comment: And How can we query the data in another list based on the ID value retrieved from the first list?

Comment: Hi @Dheeraj, It's another question? Please ask a new question. I will try to answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch value from description by using **.text()** function in the success of the function.. please refer below code

```
myAngApp.controller('spCustomerController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http({

        method: 'GET',

        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Questions')/items?$select=Description",

        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }

    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.customers = $(data.d.results[0].Description).text();


    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {



    });
```

Hope it will work for you .. :)